# Conflicting types for a function and also getting too few arguments to function call

Tags: c

I have provided a prototype before main & defined the function after main with the exact same number of arguments. I'm also calling the getline function with the same number of arguments. But I'm still getting conflicting types error & also too few arguments error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline (char line[], int maxline);
void copy   (char from[], char to[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // insert code here...
    int len;
    int max;
    char currentline[MAXLINE];
    char longestline[MAXLINE];
    max=0;
    while ( (len= getline(currentline, MAXLINE) ) > 0) {
       if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(currentline,longestline);
       }
    }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("Longest Line : %s",longestline);
    return 0;

 }

 int getline (char line[],int maxline) {
    int c,i;
    i=0;
    while((c=getchar())!='0' && (c=getchar()) !='\n') {
       if (c !='\n' && i < maxline-1) {
            line[i]=c;
       }
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        line[i++]=c;
        line[i]='\0';
    }
    return i;
 }
 void copy (char from[], char to []) {
     int i;
     i=0;
     while((to[i]=from[i])!='\0')
         i++;
  }
```

Comment: I don't get those errors when I compile your code. Which compiler are you using? How do you run it? And are you sure that this is the code that you actually are compiling, so there isn't some mistake with different versions of the file?

Comment: There's a POSIX function `getline()` taking 3 arguments, declared in `stdio.h` if you have it.  Your declaration/definition is probably conflicting with that one.

Comment: The getline function seems to be defined in Linux/GCC, although not a standard C function. Maybe you are getting a conflict with it. Have you tried to rename your getline function?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: @MiguelMuñoz `getline()` isn't standard *C*, but it is standard POSIX (POSIX.1-2008 accd. to the man page) -- it's not Linux/gcc specific.